# Ajax call infinite loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi am new to MVC so needed some help.I am making an async call to a render a partial view but it is going into an infinte loop as soon as view is called. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="headings">
    <span><a href="#">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icons/Edit.png")" alt="Edit" /></a></span>
    <p class="floatLeft">
        @Model.Name</p>
</div>
<div class="profilesBlk" id="subSections@(Model.SectionId)"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("FetchAllSubSections","Contacts")',
        data:{sectionId:@(Model.SectionId)},
        success: function (r) { $("#subSections@(Model.SectionId)").html(r); },
        error: function (ret) {
        }
    });

</script>
```

and this is where this partial view is called(This is another partial view)

```
<div>

    @foreach (var section in Model.ContactDetailSections)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Contacts/Details/SectionDetail.cshtml", section)
    }
    </div>
```

Comment: On what basis you want to call `$.ajax` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
url: '@Url.Action("FetchAllSubSections","Contacts")'
```

to

```
url: 'Contacts/FetchAllSubSections'
```